# Split Array's String Type Variable Elements

Tags: javascript, split

So I need to add different string variables to array and then split each of them by whitespace into array `splitted[]`

```js
var books = new Array()
var a = "Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet"
var b = "never gonna give you up"
var c = "another string variable"
books.push(a); books.push(b); books.push(c)

var splitted = []
for (let i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
  splitted = books[i].split(/[\s]+/)
}
console.log(splitted)
```

Expected result: `(13)['Lorem', 'Ipsum', ... 'string', 'variable']`
Actual result: `(3)['another', 'string', 'variable']`
So only the last variable `c` is splitted, while all three vars are in `books[]`.

Comment: `plitted = books[i].split(/[\s]+/)` is the problem,you need to store all the result into a global array

Comment: @lucumt _"you need to store all the result into a global array"_ - `splitted` is exactly that

Comment: You're usind `.push()` to add `a`, `b` and `c` to `books` but then `=` in the loop. Why?

Comment: Off-topic: `.push()` can handle multiple elements -> `books.push(a, b, c)`

Comment: What you mean? What's the difference, isn't `splitted[]` global? I can also write `splitted.push(books[i].split(/[\s]+/))` and output is three arrays inside the `splitted[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this but not in a best way. I simply wrote `.push(books[i].split())`, to get three arrays in `splitted[]`, then made three arrays one writing `splitted.flat(1)`

```js
var books = new Array()
var a = "Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet"
var b = "never gonna give you up"
var c = "another string variable"
books.push(a, b, c)

var splitted = []
for (let i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
  splitted.push(books[i].split(/[\s]+/))
}
splitted = splitted.flat(1)
console.log(splitted)
```

Answer (score 3):

Need to change

```
splitted = books[i].split(/[\s]+/)
```

to

```
splitted.push(books[i].split(/[\s]+/))
```

so that the latter result will not override the previous one

```js
var books = new Array()
var a = "Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet"
var b = "never gonna give you up"
var c = "another string variable"
books.push(a); books.push(b); books.push(c)

var splitted = []
for (let i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
  splitted.push(...books[i].split(/[\s]+/))
}
console.log(splitted)
```

Comment: Would be a bit cleaner with `map()` and `concat()`, or better [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap).

Comment: @SebastianSimon `flat()` might also work,and thanks  for point out,I have learned a new skill for `...Object`

Comment: Or using spread operator like so ```splitted = [...splitted, ...books[i].split(/[\s]+/)]```

Answer (score 0):

How about just using `join` and `split`?
`join` joins the three array items (a, b, c) together into one string (separated by a space `" "`) and `split` splits them up and returns all split items in a new array:

```js
var books = new Array()
var a = "Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet"
var b = "never gonna give you up"
var c = "another string variable"
books.push(a); books.push(b); books.push(c);

var splitted = books.join(" ").split(/[\s]+/)

console.log(splitted)
```

or concatenate the strings first (without pushing them to an array, although you said you wanted them in an array)

```js
var a = "Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet"
var b = "never gonna give you up"
var c = "another string variable"
var abc = a + " " + b + " " + c

var splitted = abc.split(/[\s]+/)

console.log(splitted)
```